# Intel Wireless-AC 9462 maxes out at 10Mbps

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver

O just upgraded to a 5G router, and I am not able to get Down/Up speeds above 10Mbps on my laptop using fast.com. Other devices including an iPhone on the same network and location were able to get 100+, so I can only deduce the wireless card is my bottleneck. I installed the latest drivers from Intel and used their [recommended settings for dual band](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000024678/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html?productId=125192&localeCode=us_en).

Dell Vostro running Windows 10

wifi settings:

[image: wifi settings]

Comment: Your WiFi settings clearing indicate your device is not using WiFi 5 to connect rather WiFi 4 which explains your performance issues.

Comment: @Ramhound It should still be 10x what he's getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get full dowload speed by uninstalling the SmartBytes App that comes pre-installed by Dell
https://www.dell.com/community/Networking-Internet-Bluetooth/Beware-of-SmartByte/td-p/6130892

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Just saying you did something is not the same thing as saying this is a solution. Please edit this post to make it more clear what you're saying here.

Comment: sorry i  meant to mark this as the answer but needed to wait some time before doing so and forgot....yes this fixed my issue, that app is trash apparently